# ORA-01722 invalid number error message in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, date

This is my table:

```
--Create Person Table
CREATE TABLE Person
(
Person_ID   NUMBER(10)  PRIMARY KEY,
First_Name  NUMBER(15)  NULL,
Last_Name   VARCHAR2(15)    NULL,
Middle_Name VARCHAR2(15)    NULL,
Street_Address  VARCHAR(35) NULL,
City    VARCHAR2(10)    NULL,
State   VARCHAR2(2) NULL,
Zipcode VARCHAR2(5) NULL, 
Country CHAR(2) NOT NULL, 
Birth_Date  DATE    NOT NULL,
Gender  CHAR(1)    NOT NULL,
Phone   VARCHAR2(10)    NULL,
Email   VARCHAR2(25)    NULL,
Is_Patient  CHAR(1) NULL,
Is_Physician    CHAR(1) NULL,
Is_Employee CHAR(1)  NULL,
Is_Volunteer    CHAR(1) NULL 
);
```

And I am trying to insert:

```
insert into PERSON
(Person_ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Middle_Name, Street_Address,
    City, State, Zipcode, Country, Birth_Date, Gender, Phone,
    Email, Is_Patient, Is_Physician, Is_Employee, Is_Volunteer)
values ('12333', 'Victoria', 'Tirado', 'Amanda', '1951 Lane Drive', 'Bronx', 'NY', '10467', 'US', TO_DATE('8/4/1999',
'DD/MM/YYYY'),'F','7188751200', 'heyhey@gmail.com', 'N', 'N', 'N','Y');

insert into PERSON
(Person_ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Middle_Name, Street_Address,
    City, State, Zipcode, Country, Birth_Date, Gender, Phone,
    Email, Is_Patient, Is_Physician, Is_Employee, Is_Volunteer)
values ('12444', 'Linda', 'Lewis', 'Dixon', '1366 Grey Lane', 'Bronx', 'NY', '10460', 'US', TO_DATE('7/17/1994',
'DD/MM/YYYY'),'F','7184561287', 'babygirl@gmail.com', 'N', 'N', 'N','Y');

insert into PERSON
(Person_ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Middle_Name, Street_Address,
    City, State, Zipcode, Country, Birth_Date, Gender, Phone,
    Email, Is_Patient, Is_Physician, Is_Employee, Is_Volunteer)
values ('12555', 'Kristen', 'Wardell', 'Danielle', '8112 Noble Street', 'Bronx', 'NY', '10451', 'US', TO_DATE('10/6/1997',
'DD/MM/YYYY'),'F','7189451263', 'heygirl@gmail.com', 'N', 'N', 'N','Y');

insert into PERSON
(Person_ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Middle_Name, Street_Address,
    City, State, Zipcode, Country, Birth_Date, Gender, Phone,
    Email, Is_Patient, Is_Physician, Is_Employee, Is_Volunteer)
values ('12666', 'Brittany', 'Edwards', 'Toni', '2264 Rosedale Lane', 'Bronx', 'NY', '10468', 'US', TO_DATE('4/21/1993',
'DD/MM/YYYY'),'F','7186552413', 'Itsme@gmail.com', 'N', 'N', 'N','Y');

insert into PERSON
(Person_ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Middle_Name, Street_Address,
    City, State, Zipcode, Country, Birth_Date, Gender, Phone,
    Email, Is_Patient, Is_Physician, Is_Employee, Is_Volunteer)
values ('12777', 'Kristina', 'Goodwin', 'Sue', '1010 Beach Street', 'Bronx', 'NY', '10455', 'US', TO_DATE('5/11/1991',
'DD/MM/YYYY'),'F','7189478511', 'yougood@gmail.com', 'N', 'N', 'N','Y');

insert into PERSON
(Person_ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Middle_Name, Street_Address,
    City, State, Zipcode, Country, Birth_Date, Gender, Phone,
    Email, Is_Patient, Is_Physician, Is_Employee, Is_Volunteer)
values ('12666', 'Rebecca', 'Gonzalez', 'Bianca', '8124 Elder Drive', 'Bronx', 'NY', '10474', 'US', TO_DATE('2/19/1996',
'DD/MM/YYYY'),'F','7181148792', 'artist@gmail.com', 'N', 'N', 'N','Y');

Select *
From PERSON;
```

But I am getting this message:

```
Error starting at line : 36 in command -
insert into PERSON
(Person_ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Middle_Name, Street_Address,
    City, State, Zipcode, Country, Birth_Date, Gender, Phone,
    Email, Is_Patient, Is_Physician, Is_Employee, Is_Volunteer)
values ('12666', 'Rebecca', 'Gonzalez', 'Bianca', '8124 Elder Drive', 'Bronx', 'NY', '10474', 'US', TO_DATE('2/19/1996',
'DD/MM/YYYY'),'F','7181148792', 'artist@gmail.com', 'N', 'N', 'N','Y')

Error report -
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Is it because I accidentally made first name as `Number(10)` and not `VarChar(10)`?

Comment: `First_Name  NUMBER(15)` ???

Comment: Yes - you can't put 'Rebecca' into a number field (obviously..). If you know you made that mistake already, why didn't you just fix it? Also don't put your actual numbers in quotes.

Comment: @DaleK yes it is a SQL Developer error your right. Those were just suggested tags. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @AlexPoole how to I fix it? I am a beginner at this.

Comment: @forpas how do I change it to that? I am learning this as I go

Comment: As you haven't successfully inserted any data yet, drop the table and create it again with the correct data type?

Comment: Thank you @AlexPoole, I altered it.

Answer (score 1):

`Alter table person modify (first_name varchar2(15));`

Then run your insert quety

Comment: Thank you so much @Rohit jha

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the data type that you have already altered in the table, You also need to take care of the `DATE`.

You have used: `TO_DATE('2/19/1996','DD/MM/YYYY')`. It will throw an error: `ORA-01843: not a valid month`

It should be: `TO_DATE('02/19/1996','DD/MM/YYYY')`